# Can i capture only top of image with cameraX?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I want to capture the top of an image with cameraX I know we can apply a ratio on image but when I do that the ratio is applied on the center of the image

I look on different method in ImageCaptureConfig.Builder but i found nothing relevant

```
val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
    .apply {
        setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(3, 1)) // I want this but on the top of the image
        setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
    }.build()
```

Comment: I don't think CameraX provides means for cropping captured images. You need to capture the whole image, then crop it to your liking.  Search this site for "android crop image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this code in the `ImageCapture` use case. See the official Android Camera X sample project for how they do cropping: https://github.com/android/camera/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L205

Comment: I didn't see any code related to cropping here. Can you be more specific please?